# I cant get the PhpSpreadsheet library to generates an excel sheet

Tags: php, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I use the following small PHP script using the `PhpSpreadsheet` library 1.29. Unfortunately I can't get the script to open an excel sheet. I don't get any error messages.

On my Windows PC I use XAMPP Version: 8.2.4
On the Server I use PHP 8.2
Composer version 2.6.6 2023-12-08 18:32:26

I installed the PhpSpreadsheet library with `composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet`

Using version ^1.29 for `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet`

I uploaded the files in the `vendor/phpoffice` directory to the server.

```php
<?php

// Autoloader für Composer
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

//Specify the properties for this document
$spreadsheet->getProperties()
    ->setTitle('PHP Download Example')
    ->setSubject('A PHPExcel example')
    ->setDescription('A simple example for PhpSpreadsheet. This class replaces the PHPExcel class')
    ->setCreator('php-download.com')
    ->setLastModifiedBy('php-download.com');

//Adding data to the excel sheet
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'This')
    ->setCellValue('A2', 'is')
    ->setCellValue('A3', 'only')
    ->setCellValue('A4', 'an')
    ->setCellValue('A5', 'example');


$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx"); //Xls is also possible
$writer->save("zz_excel_file.xlsx");

?>
```

I'm expecting that `$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();` will open the spreadsheet, but it doesn't

Comment: What do you mean by open the spreadsheet?

Comment: I would like to create a new spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example should work as expected.

But you're using relative paths, and that could be a problem.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$writer->save("zz_excel_file.xlsx");
```

The file is probably being written, but not to the location you expect.
It is worth either building paths using the `__DIR__` constant, or absolute paths from configuration files.

Comment: I did use an absolute path as well.

Comment: Place it at the very top
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

I checked that your code works if the PhpSpreadsheet library is installed and the paths are correct

Comment: I get the following error now:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/home/physios5/www/app.physio-und-sport.ch/vendor/composer/../ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.composer.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in /home/physios5/www/app.physio-und-sport.ch/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:41 
............. 

require('/home/physios5/...') #3 {main} thrown in /home/physios5/www/app.physio-und-sport.ch/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 41

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this. Is the library not setup correctly?

Comment: You need to either run `composer update` on the server or copy the entire `vendor` folder to the server. Most likely you did not copy the library folder on which PhpSpreadsheet depends

Comment: I did run the composer update and there was nothing to update. I also copied the whole vendor folder to the server again. But with the sae result. I will delete the whole vender folder and run the composer again.

Comment: At least, you must have a folder `vendor/ezyang` on the server, the same as local

Comment: After uploading the vendor folder again, it works just fine now. ;-) Thank you ever so much Alexander.!

Answer (score 2):

`new Spreadsheet()` doesn't open a spreadsheet, it creates a new one.

To open a spreadsheet with `PhpSpreadsheet`, you can use `IOFactory::load()`:

`$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load("path/to/your/file");`.

Have a read of [the docs](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/).

There's also [a good example here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/samples/Reader/01_Simple_file_reader_using_IOFactory.php) in the samples directory of the `PhpSpreadsheet` repository.

Comment: I would like to create a new spreadsheet.